# What is the equivalent for << from C++ in C#?

Tags: c#, c++

I just started coding in C++ and I saw in some example codes this symbol: <<
is there a equavalent in C# if so What is it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's the bit shift operator.

Comment: [Have a look at this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Comment: @djeroen It means that now you know what its called you can  use google

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx

Comment: Bit shift or stream output operator

Comment: Or nested template...

Comment: Like many other things, it can mean different thing depending on context. It can be the left bit-shift operator, it can be (and most probably is) the stream output operator, or it can mean something completely different depending on how it has been overloaded.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows zero prior research effort and the answer could be found on the internet in a few seconds.

Comment: One shouldn't really start *coding* in C++ without *learning* some C++ first, by following a good tutorial or a [good book (like from this list)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465). These would have explained it.

Comment: C# has the same operator as well, although there it is not used for stream output, although one could write a class to provide that functionality.

Comment: Also, if you're just starting out with C++, you might want to check out [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I believe the "stream output operator" is still called "bit shift operator" :)

Comment: @Mysticial `>>` can indeed be closing a nested template, but I don't think `<<` can be opening one (you'd need an identifier betweem them).

Comment: @Angew Ah dammit, you're right. *head against wall*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know anything about C#; this answer just describes the operator in C++.

It depends on context; that operator is often *overloaded* to mean different things for different types.

For integer types, it's the *bitwise left shift* operator; it takes the bit pattern of a value, and moves it to the left, inserting zero into the less significant bits:

```
unsigned x = 6;       // decimal  6, binary 00110
unsigned y = x << 2;  // decimal 24, binary 11000
```

In general, a left-shift by N bits is equivalent to multiplying by 2<sup>N</sup> (so here, shifting by 2 bits multiplies by 4).

I'm fairly sure this use of the operator is the same in C# as in C++.

The standard library overloads the operator to insert a value into an *output stream*, in order to produce formatted output on the console, or in files, or in other ways.

```
#include <iostream> // declare standard input/output streams

std::cout << 42 << std::endl;   // print 42 to the console, end the line, and flush.
```

I think C# has a `TextWriter` or something to handle formatted output, with `Console.Out` or something being equivalent to `std::cout`; but C# uses normal method calls rather than an overloaded operator.

Answer (score 2):

`operator<<` means exactly the same in C++ as it does in C#; it is the left-shift operator and moves all the bits in a number one bit to the left.

But, in C++, you can overload most operators to make them do whatever you like for user-defined types.  Perhaps most commonly, the left- and right-shift operators are overloaded for streams to mean 'stuff this thing into that stream' (left-shift) or 'extract a variable of this type from that stream' (right-shift).